# jquery sum clicked table row from given index to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

```
<tr data-index="0" data-volume="3.50" data-price="14600.01" onclick="populateSellForm(0)" data-key="11"><td>3.50</td><td>14.600,01</td></tr>
<tr data-index="1" data-volume="5.00" data-price="14449.99" onclick="populateSellForm(1)" data-key="7"><td>5.00</td><td>14.449,99</td></tr>
<tr data-index="2" data-volume="0.78" data-price="14350.00" onclick="populateSellForm(2)" data-key="5"><td>0.78</td><td>14.350,00</td></tr>
<tr data-index="3" data-volume="2.50" data-price="14349.99" onclick="populateSellForm(3)" data-key="1"><td>2.50</td><td>14.349,99</td></tr>
<tr data-index="4" data-volume="1.10" data-price="14250.00" onclick="populateSellForm(4)" data-key="15"><td>1.10</td><td>14.250,00</td></tr>
```

is there a way sum data-volume and average data-price from given index (asume given index 3) to data-index 0 with jquery

maybe you could point me right direction for i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery filter function to filter the list, and then sum and avg the result.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var sum = 0;
   var avg = 0;
   var filtered = $("tr").filter(function(){
       var id = parseInt($(this).data("index"));
       return ((id <=3) && (id >=0)); 
   });
   filtered.each(function(){
     sum+= parseFloat($(this).data("volume"))
     avg+= parseFloat($(this).data("price"))
   });
   console.log(sum);
   console.log(parseFloat(avg/filtered.length));
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr data-index="0" data-volume="3.50" data-price="14600.01" onclick="populateSellForm(0)" data-key="11"><td>3.50</td><td>14.600,01</td></tr>
<tr data-index="1" data-volume="5.00" data-price="14449.99" onclick="populateSellForm(1)" data-key="7"><td>5.00</td><td>14.449,99</td></tr>
<tr data-index="2" data-volume="0.78" data-price="14350.00" onclick="populateSellForm(2)" data-key="5"><td>0.78</td><td>14.350,00</td></tr>
<tr data-index="3" data-volume="2.50" data-price="14349.99" onclick="populateSellForm(3)" data-key="1"><td>2.50</td><td>14.349,99</td></tr>
<tr data-index="4" data-volume="1.10" data-price="14250.00" onclick="populateSellForm(4)" data-key="15"><td>1.10</td><td>14.250,00</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

> //**Call function range with start and end node to get sum and average **//

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function range(start,end){
    var sumVol  = 0;
    var sumPrice  = 0;
    var count = 0;
    for(var i=start;i<=end;i++)
    {
        sumVol += parseFloat($('tr[data-index='+i+']').attr('data-volume'));
        sumPrice += parseFloat($('tr[data-index='+i+']').attr('data-price'));
        count++;
    }
    var avgPrice = (sumPrice/count);
    return "Sum of Volume = "+sumVol+" & Average Price = "+avgPrice;
}

alert(range(1,3));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

My take on this:

1. I removed `onclick="populateSellForm(0)"` from the markup since it seems redundant because you already have `data-index` attribute.
2. Instead I attached a click event handler to rows. So, on every click on a row the sum of volumes and average price are calculated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table tr").on("click", function() {
        if(!$(this).data("volume") || !$(this).data("price")) return;
        
        var limit = $(this).data("index"),
            trs = $("table tr"),
            sumOfVolumes = 0, totalPrice = 0;

        $.each(trs, function(i, val){
            if(i === 0) return true;
            if(i > limit + 1) return false;
            sumOfVolumes += +$(trs[i]).data("volume");
            totalPrice += +$(trs[i]).data("price");
        });
        $("#limit").text(limit + 1);
        $("#volume").text(sumOfVolumes.toFixed(2));
        $("#price").text((totalPrice/(limit + 1)).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
tr:not(:first-child) {cursor: pointer; }
tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="limit">0</span> first items:<br>
Total volume: <span id="volume">0</span><br>
Average price: <span id="price">0</span><hr>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Volume</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
<tr data-index="0" data-volume="3.50" data-price="14600.01" data-key="11"><td>3.50</td><td>14.600,01</td></tr>
<tr data-index="1" data-volume="5.00" data-price="14449.99" data-key="7"><td>5.00</td><td>14.449,99</td></tr>
<tr data-index="2" data-volume="0.78" data-price="14350.00" data-key="5"><td>0.78</td><td>14.350,00</td></tr>
<tr data-index="3" data-volume="2.50" data-price="14349.99" data-key="1"><td>2.50</td><td>14.349,99</td></tr>
<tr data-index="4" data-volume="1.10" data-price="14250.00" data-key="15"><td>1.10</td><td>14.250,00</td></tr>
</table>
```